# Make string different

Tags: r

My data is as follows:

```
“Louis Hamilton”
“Tiger Wolf”
“Sachin Tendulkar”
“Lebron James”
“Michael Shoemaker”
“Hollywood – Career as an Actor”
```

- I need to extract all the characters until a space or a dash(-) is reached
- I need to extract no more than 10 characters
  My desired output is
  “Louis”
  “Tiger”
  “Sachin”
  “Lebron”
  “Michael”
  “Hollywood”

I tried using below function and it worked perfectly

```
sub("^([^- ]+).*", "\\1", v1)
```

Now, how can I manipulate these names so that the output is as follows?

```
“Louis Wolf”
“Tiger:5”
“Sachin James”
“Lebron Tendulkar”
“Michael – Actor”
“Hollywood: Shoemaker”
```

Comment: Hi,
I don't really understand what you want: why is it "Tiger:5"?

Comment: They are just an example of the output. I just wanted to randomly make the surname unique. "Tiger:5" is just an example of what I want to achieve. It can be "Tiger Hail:storm" or "Lebron:5". I want to try adding a colon too ":" am I able to make these changes to my data?

Comment: I also don't understand which rules you want to follow in order to get the desired output. If you want to append a string to a string, have a look at the ```paste``` function.